# Prevent user changing URL in browser

Tags: javascript

I want to make the URL from a next page non-editable when I open a link like this:

```
<a href="javascript:window.location='http://google.co.in?test=raj'">Enter Lobby</a>
```

Is it possible to make the `window.location` parameter non-editable through Javascript or PHP?

Comment: Do you mean: prevent the user to edit the URL in the browser?

Answer (score 6):

See [this w3schools article](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp) on `window.open`:

```
window.open("http://yoururl/", "title", "location=no");
```

The third argument are the `specs`. Pass `location=no` there.

If you want to disable URL change on the current page, sorry, that is not possible.

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply but this is open in popup window i want to open in new window to used window.location function.. this is possoble or not?

Comment: As my answer says: If you want to disable URL change on the current page, sorry, that is not possible.